# Yesod init command not found

Tags: linux, haskell, yesod

got installed haskell platform and then run

```
cabal install yesod-bin
```

but when I type

```
yesod init
```

i get "bash: yesod: command not found..."
how do I fix it ?

Comment: Please follow the up-to-date instructions on the Yesod quickstart page, which will help you avoid a lot of pain points: http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
# add local cabal binaries to command path
export PATH=~/.cabal/bin:${PATH}
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file. Alternatively, use [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md) instead of cabal for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Ok... sure `yesod-bin` installed correctly? What _is_ in the `.cabal/bin` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing `stack`  and `yesod-platform`